# Implement three-box-layout in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html

I just want to make some HTML page with [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C79XH.png).

How could I accomplish it with HTMLs `div` and CSS only, tableless.

There is a search box, hot products and an ad box.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet (and can we see it)?

Comment: this is my current layout http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50241709/upload/misc/img/layout.PNG

i just want to make some ads box below the search box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it using floats and a width of 960px;

You can adjust it to fit accordingly.

HTML:

```
<div id="area-wrap">
    <div id="hot-product">Hot Product<br />Goes<br />Here</div>
    <div id="search-box">Search Box</div>
    <div id="advertisements">Advertisements</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#area-wrap {
    width:960px;
}

#search-box {
    float:left;
    background:red;
    width:450px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#advertisements {
    float:left;
  background:blue;  
    width:450px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    color:#fff;
}

#hot-product {
    float:right;
    background:green;
    width:450px;
    margin-right:20px;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82QnL/1/ **<--- Live Demo**

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

Or you could try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eRJH3/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!

HTML File:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-left">
    top-left
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-left">
    bottom-left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    right
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS File in same directory:

```
.top-left {
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.bottom-left {
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    top: 220px;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    height: 413px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 72%;
    left: 27%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: so your response is a placeholder for later?

Comment: I posted the code, I just wanted to make sure it worked.  Why did everyone downgrade me?

Comment: thanks for the answer man, i already done it, without position :D

Comment: @11101101b I'm guessing it's because you used absolute positioning when you could have used floats. It wouldn't scale well with more content.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for full-size page and flexible layout you can do this:

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GPDBs/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    Search
</div>
<div id="ads">
    Ads
</div>
<div id="product">
    Hot Product
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    right:50%;
    bottom:40%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#product{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px; 
    right:0px;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:green;
}

#ads{
    position:absolute;
    top:60%; 
    left:0px;
    right:50%;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Is there anything that I can help? Do you want to have it with absolute positioning? Maybe if you can explain more I can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple design to make, check this out:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="search">
        search
    </div>
    <div class="products">
        products
    </div>
    <div class="ads">
        ads
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.search, .ads, .products {
    background-color:#aaa;
    margin:0 0 5px 5px;
}

.search, .ads {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}

.search {
    height:200px;
}

.ads {
    height:100px;
}

.products {
    width:550px;
    height:305px;
    float:right;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/xxbU5/show/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftTop" style="position: absolute;height: 200px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id="leftBottom" style="position: absolute;top: 220px;height: 200px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    <div id="right" style="position: absolute;left: 320px;height: 410px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid black;">
    </div>

</div>
```

and see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SC4DY/)

Comment: thanks man, but i need this on my page where position:absolute seems doesn't work